# In socket.io, how do I differentiate between 2 triggers of the same event?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Suppose I have a simple event defined as

```
socket.on('event', function(data){
    ...
});
```

And if the client fires it two times, one after another

```
socket.emit('event'); //once
socket.emit('event'); //again
```

Is there a way to *inherently** differentiate between the two events?

*I don't want want to depend on `data` because that's just a client side variable, and could easily be tampered with. (right?)

For context, it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424192/should-i-define-socket-on-event-outside-the-io-sockets-onconnection-sc).

Comment: you can create a callback, and work with way to "mark" the socket as "locked" and then when you done with it, "unlock" it again to accept data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [sessionSockets](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io) to save data for each user on the server side.

```
sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {
  socket.on('event', function() {
    if(!session.eventReceived) {
      // manage event

      // save event received in session
      session.eventReceived = true;
      session.save();
    }
  });
});
```